# how to use master/slave configuration in activemq using apache zookeeper?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to configure master/slave configuration using apache zookeeper. I have 2 application servers only on which I'am running activemq. as per the tutorial given at 
 [1]: http://activemq.apache.org/replicated-leveldb-store.html we should have atleast 3 zookeeper servers running. since I have only 2 machines , can I run 2 zookeeper servers on 1 machine and remaining one on another ? also can I run just 2 zookeeper servers and 2 activemq servers respectively on my 2 machines ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the zookeper parts of the question.
You can run two zookeeper nodes on a single server by specifying different port numbers. You can find more details at http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.2.2/zookeeperStarted.html under *Running Replicated ZooKeeper* header.

Remember to use this for testing purposes only, as running two zookeeper nodes on the same server does not help in failure scenarios.

You can have just 2 zookeeper nodes in an ensemble. This is not recommended as it is less fault tolerant. In this case, failure of one zookeeper node makes the zookeeper cluster unavailable since more than half of the nodes in the ensemble should be alive to service requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just POC ActiveMQ, one zookeeper server is enough :

```
zkAddress="192.168.1.xxx:2181"
```

You need at least 3 AMQ serveur to valid your HA configuration. Yes, you can create 2 AMQ instances on the same node : http://activemq.apache.org/unix-shell-script.html

```
bin/activemq create /path/to/brokers/mybroker
```

Note : don't forget du change port number in activemq.xml and jetty.xml files

Note : when stopping one broker I notice that all stopping.